# SqlDataAdapter returning zero rows

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to execute a stored procedure which returns data using below code.
The returned result is a table with column names, but it's not returning any rows.

```
public static DataSet ExecuteStoredProcedure()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (var context = new EFEntity())
    {
        var connectionString = ((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)context.Database.Connection).ConnectionString;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "sp.Name";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("InputParam", 12345));
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 12000; //Timeout set to max

                using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ds; // Returns 0 Rows
}
```

The stored procedure has a `select` statement and is returning result in single table as below:

[image]

Comment: So.... what is sp.Name and what does your data look like?

Comment: SP is having select statement (single table of data)

Comment: Added sample result of SP, if I expand ds, it is having table with all column names,but no result rows

Comment: try "12345" instead of 12345. SqlConnector doesn't perform implicit casting

Comment: @Steve Oh yes, I also just figured out, this was the issue. Thank you for the help

Comment: @BrootsWaymb thank you for helping, issue was because of parameter as said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your input parameter expects `string` type while your `SqlParameter` is passing in an `int`

`SqlConnector` doesn't perform implicit casting thus no result is returned.

passing in data with correct type should fix the problem.